# Codeigniter and too many database connections? (Unable to connect...)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've a lot of cronjobs (50 -100) which all start at the same time. (Refreshing data for every single client.) There are many different jobs to do in a single hour so I can't differ the times of the jobs.  And I decided not to make a loop - but single jobs - to avoid that possible errors affect the refreshs of the others.

At first all was ok - but now - having about 100 clients - nearly 30% of the jobs end up with a

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 346
```

But the max. connections of mySQL are **NOT** reached. I've already tried to switch between connect and pconnect but thas has no effect.

Any idea where the bottleneck is? And how to avoid this?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: You mean this?  `$db['live']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'; `

Comment: Are you closing connections in jobs?

Comment: @user2486495: I hope the framework does. ^^ And I've checked the max. connections of mysql. They are not reached...

Answer (score 0):

The default max connections is set to 150. If you have 100 clients and 50 to 100 cronjobs that do database queries, I come up to 100*100 = at least 10,000 connections.
If you have 10,000 connects at the same time you can get weird errors, for example time outs or concurrency problems (one script locks a table and another tries to access, this should not give an unable to connect error though but in some cases it does). You can try to bundle the queries.

What happens if you raise the max connections to 400 or so? Does it reduce the number or errors?

A workaround might be that when a job fails that you wait a second or what and try it again. More stable would be the use of a queuing mechanism like [Gearman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gearman). This helps to spread the load.

**Edit:**
Codeigniter closes connections for you, but you can do it also manually by using

`$this->db->close();`

Comment: Changing the driver to mysqli instead of mysql seems to fix it by now. But thx for the link - I'll have a look at it. (Besides: The max. connections were never reached. So mysql connections seems not to be the problem....)